# ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I tried the following query:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID, NAME, CONTACT) values(REPLACE(LE
FT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''),(SELECT LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001), 6, '0') FRO
M tm_visitor),'yatin','9876543120');
```

but I get the following error.

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tm_visitor' for update in FROM clause`

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title. Does the title reflect your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID, NAME, CONTACT) 
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), 
   LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001), 6, '0'), 
   'yatin','9876543120' 
FROM tm_visitor
```

Comment: This is due to the leading zero. You could try below:`INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID, NAME, CONTACT) 
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), 
LPAD(MAX(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM VID)) + 1, 6, '0'), 'yatin','9876543120' FROM tm_visitor;`

Comment: You could cast it as signed in the max as well.`INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID, NAME, CONTACT) 
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), 
LPAD(MAX(CAST(VID AS SIGNED )) + 1, 6, '0'), 'yatin','9876543120' FROM tm_visitor;`

Comment: Pleas explain what's actually wrong. you have fixed OP's code, but you haven't explained what went wrong so as to be useful to other people with the same or similar problems

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html) :

> This error occurs in cases […] which attempts to modify a table and select from the same table in the subquery